# Converting this MySQL_* to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I started learning PHP, I've never touched MySQL_ because everyone told me to start with PDO.

I know about PDO fetch, execute, and more. But I can't really understand how to convert this to PDO:

This is a pagination system, well a little part of it.

```
// counting the offset
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// how many rows we have in database
$sql2  = "SELECT COUNT(comment_id) AS numrows FROM comments";
$res2  = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$row2  = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
$numrows = $row2['numrows'];

// print the random numbers
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    //Echo out your table contents here.

    echo $row[1].'<BR>';
    echo $row[2].'<BR>';
    echo '<BR>';
}
```

I have no idea what mysql_fetch_array is, well it looks similar to the PDO::FETCH, but I can't really get it..

Can some one give me a few hints on how to convert this MySQL_ to PDO?

thanks.

This is the full code:

http://pastebin.com/hg1Cd246

My attempt at converting:

```
// counting the offset
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");
$res = $sql->execute();

// how many rows we have in database
$sql2  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(comment_id) AS numrows FROM comments");
$res2  = $sql2->execute();
$row2  = $res2->fetchAll();
$numrows = $row2['numrows'];

// print the random numbers
while($row = $res2->fetchAll())
{
    //Echo out your table contents here.

    echo $row[1].'<BR>';
    echo $row[2].'<BR>';
    echo '<BR>';
}
```

but getting this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

this line: 
    $row2  = $res2->fetchAll();

what did I do wrong?

Comment: Oh, look, a manual! http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: `I have no idea what mysql_fetch_array is` - that's bad news.

Comment: The `mysql_fetch_array` is "exactly" the same as [PDO::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with style `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

Comment: @Voitcus Nope. You too read the manual, please.

Comment: @Voitcus you are right, save for the last three words

Comment: @deceze Yes, I didn't know that mysql_fetch_array() also can be parametrized.

Comment: If it 'looks' like `PDO::fetch()`, well then try and implement the same action (fetch) using that, and look at the results. If they are not what you expected, *then* come back here and ask a question based on what you **did**, what you **expected**, and what you **got** instead. So far you have only met the third requirement; on Stack Overflow, all three are appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4):

> I have no idea what mysql_fetch_array is, well it looks similar to the PDO::FETCH

Well, `mysql_fetch_array` is a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) that will fetch a result (coming from `mysql_query`) into an array. `PDO::FETCH_*` instead is a [family of constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).

---

> Can some one give me a few hints on how to convert this MySQL_ to PDO?

I don't want to seem rude but you should definitely RTM: you can easily find a [proper documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

---

> Does fetchAll() does the same work as mysql_fetch_array ?

You can take a look at both the documentation for [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and [`PDOStatament::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to answer this on your own. Just to make you notice: on the linked documentation page for `mysql_fetch_array` it explicitly says:

> Alternatives to this function include: [...] PDOStatement::fetch()

---

> I'm getting this error:
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

This:

```
$res2  = $sql2->execute();
$row2  = $res2->fetchAll();
```

Is causing that error because `execute()` will return a boolean value. To retrieve results via `fetchAll()` you should call it on an `PDOStatament` (in your case `$sql2`). This is the correct code:

```
$sql2->execute();
$row2  = $sql2->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Does fetchAll() does the same work as mysql_fetch_array ?

Comment: @user2286576, you can take a look at both the documentation for [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and [`PDOStatament::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to answer this on your own.

Comment: Edited the question can u take a look please

Comment: @user2286576, change `$res2->fetchAll();` to `$sql2->fetchAll();`.

Comment: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given  mysql_free_result($res);

Comment: @user2286576, I'm **not** your debugger. Try to put some effort into solve your own problems. And only then you should ask another question on SO. You can't just keep editing a single question with all the errors you come across, hoping for an answer. I've already gone too deep this time.

Comment: I have changed mysql_free_result to $sql2->closeCursor(); plus fetchAll to just fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), now I am getting this:  Undefined variable: page_pagination This didn't happen on the mysql_* version, any idea why? + Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you're using `mysql_fetch_array` and fill it with the name of a column in your database:

```
**$row2**  = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
$numrows = **$row2['numrows']**;
```

You could use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` so you can continue using the names of column and in addition to that you can use the numeric value of columns (1st column is number 0, 2nd column 1, etc).

I'm not really common with PDO, so please look at answers from the other people aswell. Besides that, I too strongly recommend you to take a look at what different ways you can use to fetch data from your database (_rows, _assoc, _array, etc). There's lots to learn :)